# How do I open mxd backup file?

Tags: arcmap

How do I open an mxdbk file? My ArcMap froze and saved the mxdbk files. I would like to know how to open them up rather having to re-do the work.

Comment: wild guess...try renaming the extension from mxdbk to .mxd.

Comment: I forgot to mention I have ArcGIS 9.3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try renaming the extension from mxdbk to .mxd.

If that doesn't work:

Try MXD Doctor.

START --> PROGRAMS --> ARCGIS --> DEVELOPER TOOLS --> MXD Doctor